# Why is select query is very slow in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple Postgres Table. A simple query to count total records takes ages. I have 7.5 millions records in table, I using 8 vCPUs, 32 GB memory machine. Database is in same machine.

Edit: add query.

Following query is very slow:

```
SELECT * FROM import_csv WHERE processed = False ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 10000
```

Output of explain

```
$ explain SELECT * FROM import_csv WHERE processed = False ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 10000

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=5.42..49915.17 rows=10000 width=1985)
   ->  Index Scan using import_csv_id_idx on import_csv  (cost=0.43..19144730.02 rows=3835870 width=1985)
         Filter: (NOT processed)
(3 rows)
```

My table is as below:

```
      Column       |      Type      | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------------+----------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id                | integer        |           |          | 
 name              | character(500) |           |          | 
 domain            | character(500) |           |          | 
 year_founded      | real           |           |          | 
 industry          | character(500) |           |          | 
 size_range        | character(500) |           |          | 
 locality          | character(500) |           |          | 
 country           | character(500) |           |          | 
 linkedinurl       | character(500) |           |          | 
 employees         | integer        |           |          | 
 processed         | boolean        |           | not null | false
 employee_estimate | integer        |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "import_csv_id_idx" btree (id)
    "processed_idx" btree (processed)
```

Thank you

Edit 3:

```
# explain analyze SELECT * FROM import_csv WHERE processed = False ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 10000;
                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=5.42..49915.33 rows=10000 width=1985) (actual time=8331.070..8355.556 rows=10000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using import_csv_id_idx on import_csv  (cost=0.43..19144790.06 rows=3835870 width=1985) (actual time=8331.067..8354.874 rows=10001 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT processed)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 3482252
 Planning time: 0.081 ms
 Execution time: 8355.925 ms
(6 rows)
```

explain (analyze, buffers)

```
# explain (analyze, buffers) SELECT * FROM import_csv WHERE processed = False ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 10000;


                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=5.42..49915.33 rows=10000 width=1985) (actual time=8236.899..8260.941 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=724036 read=2187905 dirtied=17 written=35
   ->  Index Scan using import_csv_id_idx on import_csv  (cost=0.43..19144790.06 rows=3835870 width=1985) (actual time=8236.896..8260.104 rows=10001 loops=1)
         Filter: (NOT processed)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 3482252
         Buffers: shared hit=724036 read=2187905 dirtied=17 written=35
 Planning time: 0.386 ms
 Execution time: 8261.406 ms
(8 rows)
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** not_ just a "simple" explain

Comment: ok, but query like this is also very slow 
SELECT * FROM import_csv WHERE processed = False ORDER BY id ASC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 10000

Comment: sorry a_horse_with_no_name, I edited question, removed explain part actually.

Comment: The execution plan is important. Please add the one generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** that will contain more information that a "simple" explain

Comment: I have added explain output.

Comment: But that's the output of a "simple" `explain`, not the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: ok, I have added explain (analyze, buffers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slow because it has to dig through 3482252 rows which fail the `processed = False` criterion before finding the 10001st on which passes, and apparently all those failing rows are scattered randomly about the table leading to a lot of slow IO.

You either need an index on `(processed, id)`, or on `(id) where processed = false`

If you do the first of these, you can drop the index on processed alone, as it would no longer be independently useful (if it ever were to start with).

Comment: Thank you, I wonder reason for `(processed, id)` to be indexed. I just want to know more